# Livecharts and mouse position

Tags: c#, charts, livecharts

I would like to know if there is a way to get the position X and Y of the cursor (mouse) on the chart ?

For the moment I am stuck with the **onData** which provide me only the position of an existing point.

I would like to get the position of the mouse even if it doesn't concern a point.

For exemple, on the MS Datavisualization chart, i can get these values with :

```
Chart myChart;
ChartArea ca = myChart.ChartAreas[0];
Axis ax = ca.AxisX;
Axis ay = ca.AxisY; 
double X = ax.PixelPositionToValue(e.X);
double Y = ay.PixelPositionToValue(e.Y);
```

with e, the MouseEventArgs.

I have tried this, not work :

```
Chart_TCC.MouseMove += Chart_TCC_MouseMove;
private void Chart_TCC_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    string mouseX = e.X.ToString();
    string mouseY = e.Y.ToString();

    MessageBox.Show("X = " + mouseX + " - Y = " + mouseY);
}
```

Do you know if there is this function in the LiveCharts library ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find example of getting chart coordinates:
https://github.com/Live-Charts/Live-Charts/tree/master/Examples/Wpf/CartesianChart/SectionsMouseMove
https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/Wpf/Visual%20Elements

Comment: thank you for your help :) 
However this solution doesn't work on WinForm. :( 
I am not enough experienced in programming to start WPF...

Comment: It should work in WinForms as well. Try this link: https://github.com/Live-Charts/Live-Charts/blob/master/Examples/Wpf/CartesianChart/SectionsMouseMove/SectionMouseMoveSample.xaml.cs

Let me know what exactly is not working

Comment: Thank you again. So in the exemple they are using the "LiveCharts.Wpf.CartesianChart" but me i am using the "LiveCharts.WinForms.CartesianChart".... It looks like the developper gave up on the winform one because there is no "MouseMove" function attached to the winform one ! That's where i am stuck in fact, becaus the control doesn't have the capability to send the position of my cursor. Any idea ?

Comment: Hello again, so I investigate and found how to use the example :)
First I had to find the mouseOver in the axis properties and add the function to my .cs :
`Chart_TCC.AxisX.Chart.MouseMove += Chart_TCC_Axis_MouseMove;`
And then i followed the exemple from the link you gave me :
`var chart = (LiveCharts.Wpf.CartesianChart)sender;`
`var mouseCoordinate = e.GetPosition(chart);`
`var p = chart.ConvertToChartValues(mouseCoordinate);`
Then I get my calulated values with `p.X` and `p.Y` Thank you for helping me :)  I owe you a drink!

Comment: I am glad it worked :) By the way there is new version of Livecharts being developed rapidly. Take a look, its much faster however so far only beta available.
https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/LiveCharts2

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but it's missing so much option which are on the v1. But you are right, it is much faster.. so i'm still thinking about to rewrite some part of my code... or maybe i should rewrite all but in WPF this time. 
For the moment i will continue on my winform version, it's for me a good training to learn c# :) 
Thank you for your help !